# Need help related to Data Sets

Tags: python, dataset, bigdata, visualization, data-analysis

I have been working on a Big Data Project that requires us to work on data sets related to Child abuse and Child Maltreatment at state level or national level, in United States. We searched all the government agencies but hardly found few data sets. As per the requirement the dataset should have at least 10000 rows in it. Any ideas how to look for this.

Thanks!

Comment: Not my area but a quick google search turned up multiple datasets on the National Data Archive on Child Abuse and Neglect.

Comment: Texas data that meet your requirements can be found at https://data.texas.gov/browse?Dataset-Category_Agency=Texas+Department+of+Family+and+Protective+Services.  I am sure other states have their own data sites too.

Comment: @Jamie thanks a lot. These data sets are very useful for me. I didn't know about the state data sites. I will look for other states too. Thank you so much